# Что делать с ошибкой "Error creating SSL context ()"?

Tags: c++, qt

Делаю обычный Get-запрос. Вот код :

```
    QNetworkRequest request(URL);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(request);
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();
    qDebug() << reply->errorString();
```

Когда-то пользовался этим кодом, все работало. Сейчас почему-то получаю пустой ответ(без данных). Запросил errorString(), получил "Error creating SSL context ()". Подскажите, что с этим делать? Работаю в Ubuntu. Url рабочий, проверял.

UPD:
При использование QSslSocket::supportsSsl(); получаем:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve ERR_free_strings
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_new_null
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_push
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get_ex_new_index
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve 
 OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve 
 OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
qt.network.ssl: Incompatible version of OpenSSL
```

Comment: Вызовите после запуска программы функцию ``QSslSocket::supportsSsl()`` и посмотрите какой результат она выводит? Возможно у Вас на компьютере не установлены SSL библиотеки.

Comment: Добавил текст ошибки.

Comment: так а сам метод ``supportsSsl`` что возвращает? ``true/false``? Ну а вообще Вам в листинге указано что ``Incompatible version of OpenSSL``, так что нужно разбираться с системным OpenSSL

Comment: Возвращает false. В системе установлен OpenSSL 1.1.0g 2 Nov 2017.